# Antykwa Torunska font: How to get correct \hbar in LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, luatex, fontsize

I'm using TeX Live 2014 with `lualatex`. Using the font Antykwa Torunska (`anttor`) for math, `\hbar` is not displayed correctly. The default LaTeX settings do not give good results at all scales:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[math]{anttor}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Antykwa Torunska}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$h \hbar \frac{1}{\hbar}$

\end{document}
```

[image: \hbar without amssymb]

Using the `amssymb` package, it is possible to get a working `\hbar` symbol, albeit (of course) in an incorrect font:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[math]{anttor}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Antykwa Torunska}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$h \hbar \frac{1}{\hbar}$

\end{document}
```

[image: \hbar with amssymb]

Antykwa Torunska does include a dedicated `\hbar` glyph (the documentation shows it), but it is not easily accessible. `t2a-anttr` and `wncy-anttr` seem to include it, but I can't get to math fonts from there. How is it possible to use math symbols such as `\hbar` when the font provides them, but there is no (simple?) LaTeX interface to access them?

**EDIT:** Changed `minimal` to `scrartcl` and added TeX distribution info.

Comment: I get correct output (TeX Live 2014), apart from a spurious warning. As an aside: never use the `minimal` class; `amsmath` should go before `fontspec`.

Comment: @egreg I'm using TeX Live 2014 as well. How exactly are you getting the correct result? With or without `amssymb`? In which order are you loading the packages?

I didn't know that the `minimal` class shouldn't be used; using `scrartcl`, I get a visually identical output, however. Putting `amsmath` before `fontspec` does not change the result, either.

Comment: I'm on a different machine, now; so I pasted your first code and compiled with XeLaTeX; this [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Ojk.png) shows the output I get. The output is indeed incorrect with LuaLaTeX, though. Sorry if I couldn't get you're using LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in LuaTeX.

If, with your setup, I do

```
\sbox0{$\mkern9mu$}\showthe\wd0
\scriptspace=0pt
\sbox0{$_{\mkern9mu}$}\showthe\wd0
```

I get 5.4749pt for the first width and 5.9749pt for the second one.

It's similar if I use `newtxmath` or `fourier` for the math fonts or even if *no* font package (including `fontspec`) is loaded, when LuaLaTeX should behave like `pdflatex`.

To the contrary, if I do the same with XeLaTeX, I get 5.4749pt for the first width and 3.99998pt for the second, which accounts for the correct output that's obtained with XeLaTeX. If I omit `\scriptspace=0pt`, the second width is 4.49998pt.

This means two things:

1. LuaTeX doesn't set correctly the `mu` units in subscripts
2. LuaTeX ignores the setting to `\scriptspace`.

There's something about `\scriptspace` in the LuaTeX manual when `\Umathspaceafterscript` is described, so the status of point 2 is unclear (but it's still a bug, in my opinion).

By the way, there's also a bug in `fontspec`, because `\hbar` is treated as if it were a text symbol, while it isn't.

---

The hbar you see in the font tables for the T2A encoded version is really a Serbian Cyrillic character (in the Latin transliteration of Serbian it corresponds to ć).

You can access it as `\hbar` with this kludge:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{anttor}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Antykwa Torunska}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\hbar\relax
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\hbar}{\text{\normalfont\fontencoding{T2A}\fontfamily{antt}\itshape\symbol{163}}}%
}


\begin{document}
$h \hbar \frac{1}{\hbar}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

***News about the problem***

In a [message in the LuaTeX mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2015-January/005043.html), Luigi Scarso, a LuaTeX team member, points out thet the problem with `mu` units has been fixed, so it should be solved with the next release of TeX Live (2015).

Comment: Well, that's surprising. I wouldn't have expected a bug in such basic functionality – incorrect results for `mu` in subscripts sounds like it would be hard to miss. I suppose I should file a bug report...

Thank you for the workaround, as well. It produces the same output you've shown, but there is an error message: "`Font \T2A/cmr/m/n/10.95=larm1095 at 10.95pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont`". Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: @Socob First compile with `pdflatex` a file with `\documentclass[11pt]{article}\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` in the preamble and just `a` in the document body. Follow the discussion about the bug at http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2015-January/thread.html

Comment: Wow, that feels weird ;-)
Anyway, it worked. Thanks for solving my problem!